# terminal logging doesn't complete when I close the terminal

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, logs

This is the last line in my `.bashrc` (lines breaks inserted for readability):

```
STARTTIME=`date +%F-%Hh-%Mm-%Ss-%N`; \
script -q -t 2> /home/USER/logs/$STARTTIME-timing.txt \
       -c 'bash --rcfile /home/USER/.bashrc-cp' \
       -f /home/USER/logs/$STARTTIME-log.txt; \
gzip -9 /home/USER/logs/$STARTTIME-timing.txt /home/USER/logs/$STARTTIME-log.txt; \
exit 0
```

There is a `/home/USER/.bashrc-cp` without this mentioned last line (but it's an exact copy of my `.bashrc`).

This terminal logging solution works great. There are only two problems:

**Q1:** If I exit the gnome-terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> then the logs aren't gzipped. Why? How can I gzip them in that case?

**Q2:** I don't want to use a `.bashrc-cp` file. Are there any solutions for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**
When you ALT+F4 your terminal, it sends a SIGHUP to the shell. The shell then exits and sends a SIGHUP to everything running under that shell. Because the shell exits, it stops processing all commands, so everything after executing `script` isnt run.

The way to do this is to feed directly into gzip.

```
STARTTIME=`date +%F-%Hh-%Mm-%Ss-%N`
script -q -t -c 'bash --rcfile /home/USER/.bashrc-cp' \
-f >(nohup gzip -9 > /home/USER/logs/$STARTTIME-log.txt.gz) \
2> >(nohup gzip -9 > /home/USER/logs/$STARTTIME-timing.txt.gz)
```

What were doing here:
In bash, `>(cmd)` is special syntax that runs `cmd` and replaces `>(cmd)` with the path to a named pipe connected to `cmd`'s STDIN. The `nohup` is needed so that when the shell quits, gzip doesnt get a SIGHUP and die. Instead it will get EOF on its STDIN so it can flush its buffer and then quit.

**Q2**
I'm not sure what .bashrc-cp is. If youre trying to avoid a recursive loop you can `export STARTTIME` (or some other variable) before launching `script` and then check for its existence. If it exists, dont launch `script`.